# Display a capture device property page in Delphi - Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Firemonkey had Audio video capture classes in FMX.media. A sample for a simple capture program is available here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Video_Capturing

The question is how to display the capture device property page (for example to set backlit compensation, white balance etc). Without it this part of the framework is pretty much useless as there is no way to set the device properties.

Thanks,

/A

Comment: I don't see any reference to OleCreatePropertyFrame in FMX sources, so I doubt that Firemonkey can display device property page by simple methods

Comment: Since I have never used FMX, I wouldn't know for sure, but I would assume you need to build your own form for this which interacts with such properties.

Comment: @Jerry - thx, such properties are not exposed directly. There are no generic properties and this is the reason that every device has its own property page (to provide a different set of properties). It is possible to show a property page when using DirectShow filters directly, however I was hoping to use this simple FMX implementation. By using FMX it is not possible to set camera brightness or hue for example.

Comment: You would have to presumably provide one specific example for one specific device, and figure out how to call this screen for each one. That is, if the screen is accessible in the manner you're using it in the first place.

Comment: See also my QC entry http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111788.